# Insertion in CPP

Tags: c++

I have something like this :

```
vector<int> tmp={1,4,6,10,6};
vector<int>::iterator it1=tmp.begin()+1;
vector<int>::iterator it2=tmp.begin()+3;

// printing before insertion
cout<<*it1<<" "<<*it2<<endl;

tmp.insert(tmp.begin()+2, 200 );

//printing after insertion
cout<<*it1<<" "<<*it2<<endl;
```

I get some output like this :

```
4 10
0 10
```

Can someone help me understanding what wrong is happening here ?

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Comment: I followed it before posting. I states that "all iterators and references before the point of insertion are unaffected" .... So " it1 "  here points to element before the insertion point, so why is it affected ? Why has its value become 0 even if it is before insertion point ?

Comment: "...  unless the new container size is greater than the previous capacity (in which case all iterators and references are invalidated)"

Comment: So if I am inserting an element, doesnt that mean container size will always increase ? Under what conditions container size remain same ?

Comment: The number of items in the container will increase; the capacity of the container (which is a different thing) will increase only if the container doesn't currently have enough allocated storage to hold the additional items, and has to reallocate a new (larger) internal array in order to accomodate them.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Thanks for the reference. So that explains why it1 is invalidated, but why was it2 unaffected in this example?

Comment: @ScottK: undefined behavior.  If the vector has to reallocate the internal array, ALL existing iterators are invalidated. To make the example work correctly, use indexes instead of iterators

Comment: @ScottK I don't think it2 was unaffected; I think it *seems* unaffected because one of the (more nefarious) possible outcomes of undefined behavior is that things can *seem* to work the way you would expect in certain scenarios.  In particular, I suspect that it2 is pointing to free memory that (by dumb luck) hasn't been overwritten with new data yet.

Comment: "unless the new container size is greater than the previous capacity (in which case all iterators and references are invalidated)" . How will I (as a coder)know that new container size is becoming greater than capacity. Should I assume that its always unsafe to use iterators after insertion ?

Comment: I recommend not modifying a container during a traversal of that container.  That said, if you want to know the vector's current capacity, you can find out by calling its capacity() method.